# Checking Array Emptiness with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to determine the following JavaScript array is empty without manually iterating through it?

```
var js_array = Array("", "", "", "")
```

Comment: The array is not empty: it contains four elements.

Comment: I suppose you could test if `js_array.join('')` is true or false, but that leaves open a bunch of false positives. The fact is, that array **isn't** "empty", and you have to define exactly what you want to test for first.

Comment: You could filter and only return elements that are truthy then check the length of the array.

Comment: `Array("", "", "", "").every(String)`

Comment: @dandavis—probably better to use *Boolean* to make the type conversion explicit (thought it's one more character to type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to check whether array contains some non-empty strings.

Use `filter` to remove empty strings:

```
var tmp_js_array = js_array.filter(Boolean)
```

(see [filter documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

Then you can check whatever you want - in your case `tmp_js_array` will be empty.

Comment: That doesn't actually check whether the array contains non–empty strings, it just removes members where [*ToBoolean*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toboolean) returns false. At least a further check is required to see if the new array is the same length as the old.

Comment: You are right, since I don't know exactly what @Calvin wants to check I left this for him... (`tmp_js_array.length == 0` will do the work for example)

Answer (score 1):

There is *Array.protoype.every*, which can be used to test whether every value meets a test and returns false for the first that doesn't. So if your definition of "empty" is that all members are empty strings, then:

```
['','','',''].every(function(v){return !/\S/.test(v)}); // true
```

will return true if every member does not contain any non–whitespace characters. Alternatively, you can use *some* to see if any member contains a non–whitespace character and negate the result:

```
!['','','',''].some(function(v){return /\S/.test(v)});
```